# Increasing speed of variable length vector mean R

Tags: r, performance

I have the following code who's aim is to take a single numeric data frame column and create a list st every two elements of the vector refer to the start and end index of the data-frame  where the mean is over 0.032.

Example:

```
Input: [0.012,0.02,0.032,0.045,0.026,0.06,0.01]
Output [3,5,6,6]
```

as `mean(input(3:5))>0.032` and `mean(input(6:6))>0.032`

Slightly more complex example
Input[0,0.08,0.08,0.031,0.031,-0.1]
Output [2,5]

So I can't just identify items above 0.032, and as far as I can see I need to loop over every index. (hence the while loop)

It runs very well for for "small data-frames" but I am trying to get it to run on data-frames with 2,000,000 rows, if not more.

My issue is that it runs very slowly when I get up to a large number of rows. Specifically it shoots through the values 0-100000 but slows dramatically afterwards

```
activityduration<-function(input)
{
datum<-as.matrix(input)
len=length(datum)
times <-c()
i<-1
while (i <len)
    {
    if (i>=len)
    {
        break
    }
    i<-i+1
        if (datum[i]<0.032)
        {
            next
        }
        else
        {
        vect = c(datum[i])
        x<-i
        while ((mean(vect)>=0.032)){
            print(i)
            if (i==len)
                {
                break
                }
            i<-i+1
            boolean <- TRUE
            vect <- c(datum[x:i])
        }
        if (i==len)
                {
                break
                }
        if (boolean)
            {
            times <- c(times, c(x,i-1))
            boolean<-FALSE
            }
        }
    }
return(times)
}
```

What I assume is the issue:
I am constantly growing the vector `vect` inside the second while loop. (in some of my data `vect` can reach length = 10000). This means that I am updating `vect's` size repeatably causing the slowdown.

Fixes I have tried:
originally the input(a data-frame) was just accessed as a data-frame, I changed this to a matrix for a substantial speed increase.

I replaced else with:

```
{
newVal = c(datum[i])
x<-i
n<-0
meanValue<-0
while (((meanValue*n+newVal)>=(0.032*(n+1))){
    print(i)
    if (i==len)
        {
        break
        }
    meanValue<-(meanValue*n+newVal)/n+1
    n<n+1
    i<-i+1

    }
```

Which removed the need for the vector while maintaining the same operation, however this cause an even greater slow down. most likely due to the massive number of operations performed.

I also tried: Initialising the vector `vect` with 700000 elements so that is should never need to grow, but in order to do that I needed to change the:

`mean(vect)>=0.032` to either `sum(vect)/n >=0.032` or `mean(vect[!vect==0])`
and this results in an even greater slowdown.

Does any one know how I can increase the speed?

Comment: what is the aim? Can you provide a sample data.frame (use `dput(myDataFrame)` and the expected output?

Comment: @RichardTelford added examples at the bottom

Comment: perhaps a trivial question, but did you also try running the code without `print(i)`? Aside from that, take a look at the `microbenchmark` package. It is designed specifically for function timing.

Comment: @RichardTelford, won't that fail for an input like
 [0.001, 0.8,0.8,0.31,0.31,0.01] because it should output 2,6 as (0.08+0.08+0.032+0.032)/4>0.032. 
But using rle will skip the 0.031 inputs

Comment: @Vandenman, Ran it without print statements, didn't improve time at all

Comment: A summary of your aim would be useful in order to answer your question properly. I guess, some general performance hints could be given here (such as to avoid growing objects by initializing them before the loops are started) but I overall doubt that you really need two while loops (which is of course slowing down your code).

Comment: You could convert the code into C++ and use the packages ``Rcpp`` or ``inline`` to use it in R. This could probably increase speed by factor 10 to 100.

Comment: "Input[0,0.08,0.08,0.031,0.031,-0.1] Output [2,5]" <- shouldn't it be 1,5 as output (mean being 0.444) ? If I get you right, you aim at finding sequences in the vector where the mean is over 0,32 right ? Could they be overlapping ?

Comment: @Tensibai, That is the reason for the second if `if datum[i]<0.032, next`

I only wish to workout the means once the first value is over 0.032, this has the benefit of stopping overlaps as well

Comment: Ok, I think I see some improvements to make then, I'll see if I can get something working

Comment: @user2962956, shouldn't the output for the first example be [3,7] as `mean(input[3:7]) = 0.0346` is greater than 0.032?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another algorithm to produce the results identical to what @Joseph Wood gets.

```
activityduration <- function(input, th) {
    epsilon <- 2*.Machine$double.eps
    a <- input - th
    s <- 0; l <- 1; r <- 1; f <- F;
    n <- length(input)
    res <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 2 * n)
    j <- 0
    for (i in 1:n) {
        s <- s + a[i]
        if (s < 0 - epsilon) {
            if (f) {
                j <- j + 1
                res[c(2 * j - 1, 2 * j)] <- c(l, r)
                f <- F
            } else {
                l <- i + 1
            }
            s <- 0
        } else {
            r <- i
            if (!f) { 
                f <- T
                l <- i
            }
        }
    }
    if (f) {
        j <- j + 1
        res[c(2 * j - 1, 2 * j)] <- c(l, r)
    }
    return(res[res > 0])
}
```

**Tests on original examples**

```
print(activityduration(c(0.012,0.02,0.032,0.045,0.026,0.06,0.01), 0.032))
[1] 3 7
print(activityduration(c(0,0.08,0.08,0.031,0.031,-0.1), 0.032))
[1] 2 5
```

**Tests on @Joseph Wood's data**

```
set.seed(1313)
options(scipen = 999)
HighSamp <- sample(51:75, 10, replace = TRUE)
MidSamp <- sample(36:50, 25, replace = TRUE)
LowSamp <- sample(11:35, 30, replace = TRUE)
MinSamp <- sample(1:10, 35, replace = TRUE)
Samp1 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 20000, replace=TRUE)/1000
Samp2 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 100000, replace=TRUE)/1000
Samp3 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 1000000, replace=TRUE)/1000


JoeTest <- VariableMean(Samp1, 0.032)
SomeTest <- activityduration(Samp1, 0.032)

all(JoeTest == SomeTest)
[1] TRUE
```

**Performance tests**

```
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(Joseph=VariableMean(Samp1, 0.032), SomeAlgo=activityduration(Samp1, 0.032), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   Joseph 38.94056 39.54052 40.59358 40.41387 41.83913 42.14377    10
 SomeAlgo 38.14466 38.53188 39.47474 38.91653 40.24965 41.72669    10
microbenchmark(Joseph=VariableMean(Samp2, 0.032), SomeAlgo=activityduration(Samp2, 0.032), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   Joseph 201.9639 212.5006 226.1548 217.6033 238.1169 266.1831    10
 SomeAlgo 194.1691 200.7253 203.0191 203.6269 205.4802 211.1224    10

system.time(VariableMean(Samp3, 0.032))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.12    0.01    2.16 
system.time(activityduration(Samp3, 0.032))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.08    0.02    2.10
```

**Discussions**
1. This algorithm has a speed gain, though very moderate;
2. The core of the algorithm is to avoid direct calculation of the mean, instead it calculates if the cumulative sum changes its sign.

Comment: Very nice algorithm!! +1. Nice touch with sign usage! See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
VariableMean <- function(v, Lim) {options(scipen = 999)
    s <- which(v >= Lim)
    Len <- length(v)
    stInd <- c(s[1L], s[which(diff(s) > 1L)+1L])
    size <- length(stInd)
    myIndex <- vector(mode="integer", length = 2*size)
    bContinue <- FALSE
    epsilon <- 2*.Machine$double.eps  ## added to account for double precision

    i <- r <- 1L; j <- stInd[i]
    while (i < size) {
        k <- stInd[i+1L]-1L
        temp <- j:k
        myMeans <- cumsum(v[temp])/(1:length(temp))
        myEnd <- temp[max(which(myMeans >= (Lim-epsilon)))]
        i <- i+1L
        if (myEnd+1L < stInd[i]) {
            myIndex[2L*(r-1L)+1L] <- j; myIndex[2L*r] <- myEnd
            j <- stInd[i]
            r <- r+1L
            bContinue <- FALSE
        } else {
            bContinue <- TRUE
        }
    }

    if (!bContinue) {j <- stInd[size]}
    temp <- j:Len
    mySums <- cumsum(v[temp])
    myEnd <- temp[max(which(mySums >= Lim*(1:length(temp))))]
    myIndex[2L*(r-1L)+1L] <- j; myIndex[2L*r] <- myEnd

    myIndex[which(myIndex > 0L)]
}

VariableMean(c(0.012,0.02,0.032,0.045,0.026,0.06,0.01), 0.032)
[1] 3 7

VariableMean(c(0,0.08,0.08,0.031,0.031,-0.1), 0.032)
[1] 2 5
```

Below are some benchmarks and tests (didn't compare equality with the algorithm supplied by @Tensibai, as they don't do the same thing (i.e. there is overlap in @Tensibai's algo)):

**Test Data**

```
set.seed(1313)
options(scipen = 999)
HighSamp <- sample(51:75, 10, replace = TRUE)
MidSamp <- sample(36:50, 25, replace = TRUE)
LowSamp <- sample(11:35, 30, replace = TRUE)
MinSamp <- sample(1:10, 35, replace = TRUE)
Samp1 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 20000, replace=TRUE)/1000
Samp2 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 100000, replace=TRUE)/1000
Samp3 <- sample(c(MinSamp, LowSamp, MidSamp, HighSamp), 1000000, replace=TRUE)/1000
```

**Equality Checks/Verification**

```
JoeTest <- VariableMean(Samp1, 0.032)
OPTest <- activityduration(Samp1)
FoehnTest <- activityduration2(Samp1, 0.032)

length(JoeTest)
[1] 5466
length(OPTest)
[1] 5464

tail(JoeTest)
[1] 19966 19967 19971 19993 19999 20000
tail(OPTest)     ## OP's algo doesn't handle the end case
[1] 19960 19961 19966 19967 19971 19993

mean(Samp1[19999:20000])
[1] 0.065   ## > 0.032

all(JoeTest[1:length(OPTest)]==OPTest)  ## testing equality expect for the end
[1] TRUE

all(JoeTest==FoehnTest)
[1] TRUE

## Ensuring mean of intervals is greater than 0.032
TestMean <- sapply(seq.int(1,length(JoeTest),2), function(x) mean(Samp1[JoeTest[x]:JoeTest[x+1L]]))
all(TestMean >= 0.032)
[1] TRUE
```

**Benchmarking**

```
microbenchmark(Joseph=VariableMean(Samp1, 0.032),
                 Foehn=activityduration2(Samp1, 0.032),
                 Tensibai=Find_indexes(Samp1, 0.032),
                 OPAlgo=activityduration(Samp1), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  Joseph  18.191671  19.027055  20.362151  20.917034  21.325900  22.214652    10
   Foehn   6.848098   7.238491   8.079705   7.829212   9.083315   9.794315    10
Tensibai 140.924588 142.171712 149.936844 143.188952 148.294031 198.626850    10
  OPAlgo 122.381933 123.829385 129.934586 128.347027 136.496846 143.782135    10

microbenchmark(Joseph=VariableMean(Samp2, 0.032),
                 Foehn=activityduration2(Samp2, 0.032),
                 Tensibai=Find_indexes(Samp2, 0.032),
                 OPAlgo=activityduration(Samp2), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  Joseph  95.38979  99.82943  106.67638  101.45689  102.99117  154.21767    10
   Foehn  36.63334  37.75115   39.00842   38.97406   39.97898   41.26387    10
Tensibai 709.57490 725.15861  740.39442  737.45620  747.31374  803.22536    10
  OPAlgo 994.43310 996.61208 1025.54683 1030.84784 1046.03234 1063.52655    10

system.time(VariableMean(Samp3, 0.032))
 user  system elapsed 
0.98    0.00    1.00 

system.time(activityduration2(Samp3, 0.032))
 user  system elapsed 
0.37    0.00    0.37 

system.time(activityduration(Samp3))
 user  system elapsed 
51.37    0.42   51.82

system.time(Find_indexes(Samp3, 0.032))
user  system elapsed 
7.69    0.00    7.72
```

On my machine, the algorithm supplied by @Foehn is the fastest, and by a good bit (~ 3 times faster than mine). The @Tensibai, @Foehn, and my algorithms all seem to scale well and are stable with large data sets (as can be seen by the range in times (i.e the difference between the min and max times) from the benchmarks).

Comment: Nice one, benchmark can be compared, I get nearly the same results (1.9s) for your code on `largeinput`.

Comment: @Tensibai , I'll update with complete benchmarks once I get a little sleep

Answer (score 1):

```
Find_indexes <- function(input,target = 0.032) {
  l <- length(input)
  starts <- which(input >= target)
  seqs <- c(0,diff(starts))
  contiguousIdx <- which(seqs == 1)
  MStarts <- starts[-contiguousIdx]
  ranges <- vector('list',length(MStarts))
  current <- 1
  it <- 0
  for (i in MStarts) {
    fidx <- i
    i <- i + 1
    if (i > l) i <- l
    while (mean(input[fidx:i]) >= target) {
      i <- i + 1
      if (i > l) break
    }
    ranges[[current]] <- fidx:(i - 1)
    current <- current + 1
  }
  ranges
}

set.seed(123)
qinput <- c(0.012,0.02,0.032,0.045,0.026,0.06,0.01)
largeinput <- sample(qinput,1e6,replace = TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Find_indexes(largeinput,0.032),times=3)
```

The idea is to limit as much as possible the loops, so first we search for entries in input equal or above 0.032, next with `diff` and `wich` we search 'contiguous' entries (index just +1 or predecessor) and build a vector of starting points only.

Next we loop over those starting points and build a list of indexes while the mean from the start point to actual position is still >= to `target` (0.032 by default)

The function return a list of indexes, if you want just first and last indexe you can pass the result to `lapply` and using function `ranges`

Benchmarck results on a 1e6 vector:

```
Unit: seconds
                                      expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 result <- Find_indexes(largeinput, 0.032) 14.24063 14.25262 14.40224 14.2646 14.48304 14.70147     3
```

It is still 14s long on my machine, but this sounds better than what you have actually. (I didn't bench your solution, sorry).

There's one drawback, it records overlapping ranges.

Outputs:

```
> head(largeinput,10)
 [1] 0.032 0.060 0.032 0.010 0.010 0.012 0.045 0.010 0.045 0.045


> head(result)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 7

[[3]]
[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14

[[4]]
[1] 12 13 14

[[5]]
[1] 19

[[6]]
[1] 27 28 29

> head(lapply(result,range))
[[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]]
[1] 7 7

[[3]]
[1]  9 14

[[4]]
[1] 12 14

[[5]]
[1] 19 19

[[6]]
[1] 27 29
```